# bcrypt 3.0.6 + Node.js 12.8.1 - not compatible?

Tags: node.js, bcrypt

I have tons of warnings for installing `[bcrypt][1]` in my node.js:

```
$ npm install bcrypt

> bcrypt@3.0.6 install /var/www/html/projects/citizen-sense-dustbox-data-streams/test/node_modules/bcrypt
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

node-pre-gyp WARN Using needle for node-pre-gyp https download 
node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404): https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/releases/download/v3.0.6/bcrypt_lib-v3.0.6-node-v72-linux-x64-glibc.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for bcrypt@3.0.6 and node@12.8.1 (node-v72 ABI, glibc) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
make: Entering directory '/var/www/html/projects/citizen-sense-dustbox-data-streams/test/node_modules/bcrypt/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/blowfish.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/bcrypt.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/bcrypt_node.o
In file included from ../src/bcrypt_node.cc:1:
../../nan/nan.h: In function ‘void Nan::AsyncQueueWorker(Nan::AsyncWorker*)’:
../../nan/nan.h:2232:62: warning: cast between incompatible function types from ‘void (*)(uv_work_t*)’ {aka ‘void (*)(uv_work_s*)’} to ‘uv_after_work_cb’ {aka ‘void (*)(uv_work_s*, int)’} [-Wcast-function-type]
     , reinterpret_cast<uv_after_work_cb>(AsyncExecuteComplete)
                                                              ^
In file included from ../../nan/nan.h:53,
                 from ../src/bcrypt_node.cc:1:
../src/bcrypt_node.cc: At global scope:
/home/lau/.cache/node-gyp/12.8.1/include/node/node.h:556:43: warning: cast between incompatible function types from ‘void (*)(Nan::ADDON_REGISTER_FUNCTION_ARGS_TYPE)’ {aka ‘void (*)(v8::Local<v8::Object>)’} to ‘node::addon_register_func’ {aka ‘void (*)(v8::Local<v8::Object>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, void*)’} [-Wcast-function-type]
       (node::addon_register_func) (regfunc),                          \
                                           ^
/home/lau/.cache/node-gyp/12.8.1/include/node/node.h:590:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘NODE_MODULE_X’
   NODE_MODULE_X(modname, regfunc, NULL, 0)  // NOLINT (readability/null_usage)
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
../src/bcrypt_node.cc:378:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘NODE_MODULE’
 NODE_MODULE(bcrypt_lib, init);
 ^~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/lau/.cache/node-gyp/12.8.1/include/node/node.h:63,
                 from ../../nan/nan.h:53,
                 from ../src/bcrypt_node.cc:1:
/home/lau/.cache/node-gyp/12.8.1/include/node/v8.h: In instantiation of ‘void v8::PersistentBase<T>::SetWeak(P*, typename v8::WeakCallbackInfo<P>::Callback, v8::WeakCallbackType) [with P = node::ObjectWrap; T = v8::Object; typename v8::WeakCallbackInfo<P>::Callback = void (*)(const v8::WeakCallbackInfo<node::ObjectWrap>&)]’:
/home/lau/.cache/node-gyp/12.8.1/include/node/node_object_wrap.h:84:78:   required from here
/home/lau/.cache/node-gyp/12.8.1/include/node/v8.h:9853:16: warning: cast between incompatible function types from ‘v8::WeakCallbackInfo<node::ObjectWrap>::Callback’ {aka ‘void (*)(const v8::WeakCallbackInfo<node::ObjectWrap>&)’} to ‘Callback’ {aka ‘void (*)(const v8::WeakCallbackInfo<void>&)’} [-Wcast-function-type]
                reinterpret_cast<Callback>(callback), type);
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/lau/.cache/node-gyp/12.8.1/include/node/v8.h: In instantiation of ‘void v8::PersistentBase<T>::SetWeak(P*, typename v8::WeakCallbackInfo<P>::Callback, v8::WeakCallbackType) [with P = Nan::ObjectWrap; T = v8::Object; typename v8::WeakCallbackInfo<P>::Callback = void (*)(const v8::WeakCallbackInfo<Nan::ObjectWrap>&)]’:
../../nan/nan_object_wrap.h:65:61:   required from here
/home/lau/.cache/node-gyp/12.8.1/include/node/v8.h:9853:16: warning: cast between incompatible function types from ‘v8::WeakCallbackInfo<Nan::ObjectWrap>::Callback’ {aka ‘void (*)(const v8::WeakCallbackInfo<Nan::ObjectWrap>&)’} to ‘Callback’ {aka ‘void (*)(const v8::WeakCallbackInfo<void>&)’} [-Wcast-function-type]
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib.node
  COPY Release/bcrypt_lib.node
  COPY /var/www/html/projects/citizen-sense-dustbox-data-streams/test/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node
  TOUCH Release/obj.target/action_after_build.stamp
make: Leaving directory '/var/www/html/projects/citizen-sense-dustbox-data-streams/test/node_modules/bcrypt/build'
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
+ bcrypt@3.0.6
added 68 packages from 49 contributors and audited 97 packages in 3.525s
found 0 vulnerabilities
```

I am on node 12.8.1:

```
$ node -v
v12.8.1
```

Any ideas what I can do?

Comment: It sounds like pre-built binaries weren't found so it just built it from scratch.  The warning about a cast between incompatible types sounds like there may have been a node.js add-on API change.